# PHP. Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, fatal-error

I've got a problem

I'm new to PDO, so i'm trying to get all data from a tabla, very easy i know, but $this variable is giving me some problem, i wrote a class called DB to connect to mysql, and i use it in another class called getAll with a function called get;

DB class

```
<?php 
class DB
{
    private $_dbh;
    private static $_instance;
    private function __construct()
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=telmex","root","a.d.s.l");                   
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }
    }

    public static function Link()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$_instance;    
    }
}
```

?>

getAll Class

```
<?php 

class getAll
{
    public $_dbh;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_dbh=DB::Link();
    }

    public static function get($tabla)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tabla."";
        if($sentencia=$this->_dbh->prepare($sql))
        {
            echo "Prepared.";
        }   
    }
} ?>
```

So when i run

```
<?php 
$select = new getAll();
    $consultar = $select->get("users");
 ?>
```

it gives me a fatal error.

Comment: remove the `static` from the definition of `public static function get($tabla)` because you're not calling it statically, you're treating it as an instance method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error For $this variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280439/fatal-error-for-this-variable)

Comment: Still giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from getAll class public $_dbh; and make it extend of DB class

Comment: Except there won't be a valid database connection unless you make a few other changes as well

Comment: can you write exactly what is the problem from apache log ?

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/html/PDO/Clases/getAll.php on line 14

Comment: remove this line from getAll class public $_dbh; and make it extend of DB class

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class getAll extends DB {
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }
    public static function get($tabla)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tabla."";
        if($sentencia=$this->_dbh->prepare($sql))
        {
            echo "Prepared.";
        }   
    } 
 }
getAll::get('users');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

DB class

```
<?php 
class DB
{
    var $_dbh;
    private static $_instance;
    private function __construct()
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=telmex","root","a.d.s.l");                   
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }
    }
    function get_dbh(){
        return $this->_dbh;  
    }
    public static function Link()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$_instance;    
    }
}
?>
```

getAll Class

```
<?php 

class getAll
{
    public $_dbh;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $con = DB::Link();
        $this->_dbh= $con->get_dbh();
    }

    public static function get($tabla)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tabla."";
        if($sentencia=$this->_dbh->prepare($sql))
        {
            echo "Prepared.";
        }   
    }
} ?>
```